# Angular 12, set variable from function

Tags: angular, typescript, this, ngoninit

I'm developing a little tool where I need to populate a variable on component creation.
I've declared variable here:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
myVar: any
```

and try to set its value here:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    setInterval(() => this.myFunction(5), 3000);
  }

  myFunction(arg: number): void {
    this.data.forEach(function (this: HomeComponent, element: any) {
      if (element.id === number) {
        this.myVar = element.id;
      }
    });
  }
```

but no value was passed and I get this error:
"ERROR TypeError: this is undefined"

Any idea?
Thank you in advice!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible just to reference `this: HomeComponent` and send data to `HomeComponent`. Using `this`,`that` references belong to vanilla JS world, let's leave them there.

You have declared `myFunction` takes in one param type of number. Why haven't you supplied a number in `setTimeout()`? It can never work like that.

I don't see where is `this.data` coming from, so I am going to assume what you want to achieve here is when components are sharing data.

I am going to create an example for you where child component `HelloComponent` will send data to parent component `AppComponent`. A) When you click button send data and B) like your example, with `setTimeout()` delay.

We create a an event, that we emit from child and parent will catch the event and then show the data (string) carried by the event.

Child

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1><button (click)="sendMessage()">Send Message</button>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
})
export class HelloComponent {
  message: string = 'Receiving Message from child';
  @Output() messageEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    setInterval(
      () => this.messageEvent.emit('hello, I am delayed meesage'),
      5000
    );
  }

  sendMessage() {
    this.messageEvent.emit(this.message);
  }
}
```

Parent

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  message:string='';

  receiveMessage(sentMessage: string): void {
    this.message = sentMessage;
  }

}
```

```html
{{message}}
<hello (messageEvent)="receiveMessage($event)"></hello>
```

Here is a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-child-parent-1-s9q62k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Here is more info how to use @Input/@Output decorators. https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Comment: Thanx,
no, I don't need to share data, I'm getting object from api call made in a service, and i need to check if some data is present in it.
If I can find it I have to update variable value, but I can't figure out how can I do

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions do not have their own 'this'. Arrow functions establish "this" based on the scope the Arrow function is defined within.

Try to change the code like below by just sending the myFunction as reference

```
setInterval(myFunction, 3000);
```